# Tramp mode: How check only one per day?

Tags: tramp

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 26.1

I open **trace.log** file from remote Linux machine by `Tramp` mode.

Nice.

I set custom variables:

```
'(password-cache-expiry nil)
'(auto-revert-remote-files t)
```

I set variable `auto-revert-remote-files t` because I need to see content of remote file interactively (on fly).

But when file **trace.log** is change (by external web application) I get the next message in minibuffer:

```
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Copying /pscp:mylogin@remote_ip_machiney_ip:/root/logs/trace.log to c:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Temp/tramp.2iBhRe.log...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/ppscp:mylogin@remote_ip_machiney_ip:/home/myproject/logs/trace.log’...done

    Tramp: Checking ‘vc-registered’ for /pscp:mylogin@remote_ip_machiney_ip:/root/back/myapp/logs/trace.log...done
    Tramp: Inserting ‘/pscp:mylogin@remote_ip_machiney_ip::/root/back/myapp/logs/trace.log’...done
```

File **trace.log** on remote machine is periodically changes by web application.

How disable this message on minibuffer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the messages to disappear from your minibuffer, decrease the value of `tramp-verbose`. 1 means to display only error messages, 0 suppresses Tramp messages at all.

However, I don't understand why you see such messages. If you visit a (remote) file in a buffer, nothing will happen if the file changes externally, as long as you don't try to write. What makes these messages appear in your minibuffer? How did you load the remote file?

Comment: I open remote file via Tramp mode. Like this: /pscp:my_login@my_ip:/home/my_app/

Comment: Do you have enabled something like (global) autorevert?

Comment: Yes, I set  '(auto-revert-remote-files t). I set this variable because I need to see content of remote file interactively.

Comment: Well, this is the reason why the file is reloaded. So I recommend to disable `auto-revert-mode` for this file, if you want to have it reloaded once a day only. This could be done manually.

Comment: But I need to see content of remote file interactively (on fly).

Comment: Then you must decrease the value of `tramp-verbose` as described in my answer. BTW, a better way to see the contents of a log file is to apply `auto-revert-tail-mode` instead of `auto-revert-mode`.

Comment: '(tramp-verbose 0 nil (tramp))  - not help. So I remove  '(auto-revert-remote-files t) and the problem is gone.